# Understanding shift/reset in Racket

Tags: functional-programming, racket, continuations, delimited-continuations

I present two naive implementations of `foldr` in racket

This first one lacks a proper tail call and is problematic for large values of `xs`

```
(define (foldr1 f y xs)
  (if (empty? xs)
      y
      (f (car xs) (foldr1 f y (cdr xs)))))

(foldr1 list 0 '(1 2 3))
; => (1 (2 (3 0))
```

This second one uses an auxiliary function with a continuation to achieve a proper tail call making it safe for use with large values of `xs`

```
(define (foldr2 f y xs)
  (define (aux k xs)
    (if (empty? xs)
        (k y)
        (aux (lambda (rest) (k (f (car xs) rest))) (cdr xs))))
  (aux identity xs))

(foldr2 list 0 '(1 2 3))
; => (1 (2 (3 0)))
```

Looking at `racket/control` I see that racket supports first-class continuations. I was wondering if it was possible/beneficial to express the second implementation of `foldr` using `shift` and `reset`. I was playing around with it for a little while and my brain just ended up turning inside out.

Please provide thorough explanation with any answer. I'm looking for big-picture understanding here.

Comment: The first one looks the same as the one provided in racket. If racket doesn't need to complicate it why do you need to?

Comment: @Sylwester I didn't want to concentrate on `foldr` itself, but more on how to express the procedure with a proper tail call using different techniques. I was only using `foldr` as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disclaimers:*

1. *The “problem” of `foldr` you are trying to solve is actually its main feature.*
2. *Fundamentally, you cannot process a list in reverse easily and the best you can do is reverse it first. Your solution with a lambda, in its essence, is no different from a recursion, it’s just that instead of accumulating recursive calls on the stack you are accumulating them explicitly in many lambdas, so the only gain is that instead of being limited by the stack size, you can go as deep as much memory you have, since lambdas are, likely, allocated on the heap, and the trade off is that you now perform dynamic memory allocations/deallocations for each “recursive call”.*

*Now, with that out of the way, to the actual answer.*

---

Let’s try to implement `foldr` keeping in mind that we can work with continuations. Here is my first attempt:

```
(define (foldr3 f y xs)
  (if (empty? xs)
    y
    (reset 
      (f (car xs) (shift k (k (foldr3 f y (cdr xs))))))))
  ; ^ Set a marker here.
  ;    ^ Ok, so we want to call `f`.
  ;               ^ But we don’t have a value to pass as the second argument yet.
  ;                 Let’s just pause the computation, wrap it into `k` to use later...
  ;                 And then resume it with the result of computing the fold over the tail.
```

If you look closely at this code, you will realise, that it is exactly the same as your `foldr` – even though we “pause” the computation, we then immediately resume it and pass the result of a recursive call to it, and this construction is, of course, not tail recursive.

Ok, then it looks like we need to make sure that we do not resume it immediately, but rather perform the recursive computation first, and *then* resume the paused computation with the recursive computation result. Let’s rework our function to accept a continuation and call it once it has actually computed the value that it needs.

```
(define (foldr4 f y xs)
  (define (aux k xs)
    (if (empty? xs)
      (k y)
      (reset
        (k (f (car xs) (shift k2 (aux k2 (cdr xs))))))))
  (reset (shift k (aux k xs))))
```

The logic here is similar to the previous version: in the non-trivial branch of the `if` we set a `reset` marker, and then start computing the expression as if we had everything we need; however, in reality, we do not have the result for the tail of the list yet, so we pause the computation, “package it” into `k2`, and perform a (this time tail-) recursive call saying “hey, when you’ve got your result, resume this paused computation”.

If you analyse how this code is executed, you’ll see that there is absolutely no magic in it and it works simply by “wrapping” continuations one into another while it traverses the list, and then, once it reaches the end, the continuations are “unwrapped” and executed in the reverse order one by one. In fact, this function does exactly the same as what `foldr2` does – the difference is merely syntactical: instead of creating explicit lambdas, the `reset`/`shift` pattern allows us to start writing out the expression right away and then at some point say “hold on a second, I don’t have this value yet, let’s pause here and return later”... but under the hood it ends up creating the same closure that `lambda` would!

I believe, there is no way to do better than this with lists.

*Another disclaimer: I don’t have a working Scheme/Racket interpreter with `reset`/`shift` implemented, so I didn’t test the functions.*